# how to use html with l20n.js

Tags: javascript, l20n

I've a little problem with l20n.js, the HTML in my strings is always escaped :/ .

I use l20n like this :

```
<div class="col-twelve" data-l10n-id="intro-text">
    <h5>my <span style="color: whitesmoke">Title</span></h5>
    <h1>Bienvenue <span class="title-separator"></span> Welcome <span class="title-separator"></span> Willkommen</h1>
    <h5>Intro</h5>
</div>
```

And in my fr.ftl :

```
intro-text = 
    |   <h5>Mon <span style="color: whitesmoke">Titre</span></h5>
    |    <h1>Bienvenue <span class="title-separator"></span> Welcome <span class="title-separator"></span> Willkommen</h1>
    |   <h5>texte intro</h5>
```

But, l20n.js render the text like this :

```
<div class="col-twelve" data-l10n-id="intro-text">
  |   Mon titre
  |   Bienvenue  Welcome  Willkommen
  |   texte intro
</div>
```

I've already done some searches

- In the l20n tinker : http://l20n.github.io/tinker/ we can check/uncheck a checkbox to escape html or not, but I didn't found this option in the API :/ .

So, I'm a little lost .

Do you have any idea ? or any other javascript framework to do translation easyly ? ( I need to have : separate locales files, no backend only ngninx, easy to read/write translation for a no-IT )

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, so yesterday isn't work ... and today it's work ...

I've just change my ftl from :

```
intro-text = 
|   <h5>Mon <span style="color: whitesmoke">Titre</span></h5>
|    <h1>Bienvenue <span class="title-separator"></span> Welcome <span class="title-separator"></span> Willkommen</h1>
|   <h5>texte intro</h5>
```

to :

```
intro-text = 
 <h5>Mon <span style="color: whitesmoke">Titre</span></h5>
 <h1>Bienvenue <span class="title-separator"></span> Welcome <span class="title-separator"></span> Willkommen</h1>
 <h5>texte intro</h5>
```

Maybe the ftl need only one space before text :/ .